# Passing String with Notification and then pass to class

Tags: iphone, subclass, userinfo, nscfstring

I have a question I work for an ipad application, in this app on main view I have an instance of a custom uitableviewcontroller, on row click I post a notification that pass an object and run a method

```
- (void) drawWebView:(id) sender {

    NSDictionary *dict = [[sender userInfo] copy];
    self.objTesto = [dict objectForKey:@"Testo"];
    self.txtWeb = self.objTesto.testo;

    //[self setWebView:self.txtWeb];
    [self.textWebView loadRequest:[self creaFileHTML:text]];
}
```

while I set the load request on the webview of my class all work, If I creat a subclass of uiwebview with a method setWebView: whit a simple NSLog()

```
[self setWebView:self.txtWeb];
//[self.textWebView loadRequest:[self creaFileHTML:text]];
```

I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString userInfo]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xee3a1e0'

Comment: What's the relationship between `drawWebView:` and `setWebView:`?  (I would also change `drawWebView:(id) sender` to `drawWebView:(NSNotification *) notification` so that you catch type errors at compile time.)

Comment: no reletion, drawWebView is on main view, this method run when mainview recive notification from uitableviewcontroller, setView is a method of uiwebview subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that I init the wrong class (I have two similar class) - stupid error -.- excuse me!

Answer (score 0):

Either the wrong thing is being passed as a parameter or else you have a memory management problem.  You need to find out how a string is being asked for its `userInfo`.

If you change the parameter declaration and turn on zombies in your scheme, it should become clear which is happening.